# Bootstrap CDN shows steps in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am coming from a C# background where i do basically winform to Web where i have to make good UI and a good form, now i am trying to make a Form using Bootstrap as i know how to do backend and all. now i want to learn how to use Bootstrap for Frontend as i see , most jobs are Web Based now.

Now My code Looks like this, and its very scattered.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>New Bootstrap test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<h3>Test Form </h3>

<body>
<form class="form-hotizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php"/>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for ="fullname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class ="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="fullname" placeholder="Name in Full" value="" />
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for ="telephone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telephone</label>
    <div class ="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for ="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class ="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for ="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID Number</label>
    <div class ="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idnumber" name="idnumber" placeholder="ID Number" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class ="col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run it in browser instead of displaying a correct form, it just arranges them like staircases. I am new to this hence, I need help in this case.

Comment: You never closed your `<div class="form-group">`s EDIT: or any other div for that matter

Comment: @SourceOverflow thanks , its better now , so how do i make it not to stretch to the full page of the screen ?

Comment: make their widths smaller? (in bootstrap prob. by using the grid system)

Comment: sourcing for tutorials on how to make Widths smaller for textbox. Page is Responsive now, Challenge is the Textbox Fills the Entire screen. Code has been updated Further for your viewing @SourceOverflow

Comment: `width: asmallernumber;`? Since Bootstrap uses a gridsystem and since you apparently use it, use the premade `col-{screen}-{nr. of col.}` system. E.g. you already used `col-sm-2`, which makes them 2 columns wide (out of 12 by default) on small screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing div tags. There was also a typo in the form-horizontal class. Here is the corrected version. Here is a codepen for a [demo](https://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/GOQZLP). For every starting div tag, there should be a closing div.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="fullname" placeholder="Name in Full" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telephone</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" value="" />

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idnumber" name="idnumber" placeholder="ID Number" value="" />

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```